# How can I configure Spring Scheduled Task to run in a time range with specific delay?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need set up *spring scheduled time* to be executed every 15 minutes from 5 p.m till 8 a.m, how to specify such expression? And also I'd like task be executed on weekdays not just MON-FRI, but according to my implementation of isBusinessDay logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Maven Dependency**

Part of [Spring Context](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context)

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Configuration to enable Scheduling**

[Reference from Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-enable-annotation-support)

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyAppConfig {
//..
}
```

**Method to fire on the Cron you specified**

[Reference from Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)

```
// 0/15 -> Every 15 minutes on the clock
// 17-20 -> Between 5pm and 8pm on the JVM timezone
// if you want timezone specific there is a 'zone' parameter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#zone--
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/15 17-20 * * ?")
public void doSomething() {
    // ..
}
```

**Documentation**

[Spring Documentation on Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support)

**Spring Boot**

[Spring Boot example of setup to run for the above cron](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

May be this link can help you.
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example1.html

Answer (score 0):

On the safe site you need to add the time-zone of the respective country

```
// 0/15 -> Every 15 minutes on the clock
// 17-20 -> Between 5pm and 8pm 
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/15 17-20 * * ?",zone="Your time zone")
Ex:--
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/15 17-20 * * ?",zone="Asia/Calcutta")
public void yourJob(){
..........
..........your code
..........
}
```

Below is some basic configuration corn expression

```
The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

Example patterns:

"0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
"*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
"0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
"0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
"0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```